# WPF Frame, Scrollviewer, Listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, frame, scrollviewer

I am using frame & pages in my application. The logic behind my XAML is as follows.

Window
I have a window, in that window is a scrollviewer that has a frame inside it who's source is set to "Page1.xaml".

Page 1
Inside Page1.xaml, i have a list box with margins of 10, vertical & horizontal alignment is set to stretch.

The Problem
I am wanting to be able to scroll the mouse while inside the listbox. With this current set up i am unable to scroll while i am inside the listbox. However, when i set a height and DO NOT have Vertical alignment set to stretch, i am able to scroll inside the listbox.

Here is the XAML Code for the window & Page:

MainWindow.XAML

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Frame  NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both"                   
                x:Name="_mainFrame" Background="#FFC3C3C3">
    </Frame> 
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Page1.XAML

```
 <Grid>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Margin="50,10,50,29" MinHeight="200" Grid.Row="2"                   
                 VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" Background="White" OpacityMask="White" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: What happens if you set the Grid in Page1.xaml to `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and leave the ListBox as it is?

Comment: _"The Problem I am wanting to be able to scroll the mouse while inside the listbox"_ [...] _"However, when i set a height and DO NOT have Vertical alignment set to stretch, i am able to scroll inside the listbox."_  It seems you have solved your problem by yourself. Great!

Comment: Still gives the same issue. The reason i dont want the listbox to have a fixed height is because when the window is re-sized, i am wanting the listbox to re-size accordingly. If i have a fixed height, when the window is re-sized, the listbox will not re-size which will alter the GUI of the other controls around it.